# Binding not working with Track changes enabled in Office.js Word

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm working Office App for Word using `Office.js` which has to detect changes whenever any content is changed inside a content control. For that I have used binding as shown below:

```
private createBindingOnContentControl = (title: string) => {

    //this method creates a Binding and Subscribes to DataChanged Event.
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(title, Office.BindingType.Text, { id: title }, (result) => {
      if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        console.log("Binding successfull for cc: ", title);
        //binding created! lets subscribe to the event.
        result.value.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, this.onBindingChangeHandler);
        result.value.removeHandlerAsync;
      } else console.log(result.error.message);
    });
  }
```

It's working fine if I haven't set the track changes enabled from review tab but If I enabled the track changes feature, now if I add any additional content in a content control it marked as red and `OnBindingChangeHandler` called fine but if I remove any content which is marked red with strike through, the `OnBindingChangeHandler` isn't called. Is the binding didn't worked when you remove content when track changes is enabled or am I missing something or doing something wrong ?

Comment: This might be a bug. Please wait a few days and if you don't get answer here, consider creating an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: @RickKirkham Should Iadd that as an issue on office-js repo or have to wait ? It's something which is urgent for us.

Comment: I let you decide how long to wait. It is a general good practice to let the Stack community have a chance before you create an issue.